# Mongoose Using Enum with Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose

The `user` schemas has the key, `bookmarks`, where the user can mark **discussions** and **responses** as bookmarked, but I'm not sure how to specify that in my schema.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  bookmarks: [ {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Discussion' // <-- Discussion or Response dynamically
  } ],
});
```

I looked into Mongoose Enum's but I was unable to determine that in the backend which one it was.

How do I:

- Set enum `ref` in Schema
- Make request via Redux action creator and sending the `id`
- Allow backend to determine if it's `Discussion` or `Response`
- How do I later access it through Express/Mongoose

**The way I'm expecting this to work:**

- User clicks the *bookmark* button on either a `Discussion` Card or `Response` Card
- Redux fires an action creator to make a `POST` request to `/api/bookmark/:itemId`
- Express figures out whether it's `Discussion` or `Response` and `unshifts` item to `bookmarks` key
- When user makes a `GET` request to get all bookmarks, Mongoose **populates** the bookmarks array and sends back the result